# Filter ng-repeat by date month and year

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have the following variable:

```
scope.availabilities = [
    {
        date : "2014-10-01 07:00:00",
        intervals : [...]
    },
    {
        date : "2014-10-02 07:00:00",
        intervals : [...]
    },
    ...
]
```

I have a date picker, and you can select to see each month. Let's call this `scope.month`. Currently, I save this as an array of `scope.month = [year, month]`, for instance `scope.month = [2014, 10]` because I want to be able to display each month's availabilities.

Now, I want use `ng-repeat`, but filter these `availabilities` based on their `date` and only show the selected month.

The only way I can think of doing this is to have my own custom filter, i.e.

```
<div ng-repeat="availability in availabilities | filterByDate:month">
```

And then have my filter defined as:

```
app.filter('filterByDate', function()
{
    return function(availabilities, month)
    {
        // Here do the filtering, for instance, using underscore _.filter
    }
});
```

But is there a way I could do this natively using AnuglarJS built in filters?

Comment: Not by using the AngularJS built in filters but you could use this filters extention: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter which is pretty popular this days (take a look at toArray filter)

Comment: @DinRevah, oh wow thanks! that's fantastic. I'll use this for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
app.filter('filterByDate', function()
{
    return function(availabilities, month)
    {
        // Here do the filtering, for instance, using underscore _.filter
        return availabilities.filter(function(item){ 
             var parts = item.date.match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})$/);
             return month[1]===parseInt(parts[2]) && month[0]===parseInt(parts[1]);
        });

    }
});
```

If the month that you are saving in `$scope.moth` is base 0 (0-11) and the month of the dates in "availabilities" are not in base 0, then you should change this line:

```
             return month[1]+1===parseInt(parts[2]) && month[0]===parseInt(parts[1]);
```

### Update

You could actually accomplish the same thing using the [`$filter`filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) combined with a custom function, like this:

In your controller define a function like this:

```
$scope.filterByMonth = function(month){
   return function(item){ 
      var parts = item.date.match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})$/);
      return month[1]===parseInt(parts[2]) && month[0]===parseInt(parts[1]);
   };
}
```

And then in your view you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="availability in availabilities|filter:filterByMonth(month)">
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I do realize that I could make a custom filter. I was wondering if there were any in-built filters by Angular itself that cold do this.

Comment: @Kousha actually yes, you could accomplish the same thing using the **[`$filter` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)**. I will update my answer with an example.